# Perform Windows File Search from Terminal/cmd/PowerShell

Tags: windows-11, windows-search, file-search

How do I perform an indexed Windows File Search from Terminal (like cmd or Powershell)?
I'm looking for an equivalent of `mdfind` of MacOS.

Comment: Have you tried the FIND command?    find /?  to see what it does.

Comment: Well I want to use it to find files containing a certain string that could be anywhere on my disk, and this in reasonable time using the windows search index. Recursively passing all files on my disk to FIND does not appear to be an efficient way.